# How can I make this timer() work as I want?

Tags: java, swing, timer, colors, jframe

I am having a bit of trouble with the code before. It is doing what I want, but I can only call the method once, if I call it more than that it won't work, essentially it only works once. So right now this ballG is an object. It starts off as White, it sets it to green, has a delay, then sets it back to white, this is perfect. The problem is since I do timerG.start(); and I don't end it, when I call it again it doesn't work. If I do timerG.stop(); it ignores the action event and leaves it green without going back to white. How can I make it so I can call this method multiple times???

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;


public class frame extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textEntered;
private JTextArea displayT;
private JTextPane textPane;
private JLabel instructions;
private JLabel instructions3;
private JLabel instructions2;
private JLabel ballR;
private JLabel ballG;
private JLabel ballB;
private JPanel panel;
private JTextArea textArea;
private JLabel instructions4;

public String translator(String x)
{
    String y = "";
    for(int i = 0; i< x.length(); i++)
    {
        y = y + code(x.charAt(i)) + " ";
    }
    return y;

}

private String code(char a)
{

    switch (a) {
    case 'e' :  return "R"; 
    case 't' : return "B"; 
    case 'a' : return "G"; 
    case 'o' : return "RB"; 
    case 'i' : return "RG"; 
    case 'n':  return "BG"; 
    case 's' :  return "R-R"; 
    case 'h' :  return "R-B"; 
    case 'r' :  return "R-G"; 
    case 'd' :  return "R-RB"; 
    case 'l' :  return "R-RG"; 
    case 'c' : return "R-BG"; 
    case 'u' : return "B-R"; 
    case 'm' : return "B-B"; 
    case 'w' : return "B-G"; 
    case 'f' :  return "B-RB"; 
    case 'g' :  return "B-RG"; 
    case 'y' :  return "B-BG"; 
    case 'p' : return "G-R"; 
    case 'b' : return "G-B"; 
    case 'v':  return "G-B"; 
    case 'k' : return "G-RB"; 
    case 'j' :  return "G-RG"; 
    case 'x' :  return "G-BG"; 
    case 'q' :  return "RB-R"; 
    case 'z' :  return "RB-G"; 
    case ' ' :  return "RB-B";  
    case '0' : return "RB-RB"; 
    case '1' : return "RB-RG"; 
    case '2' :  return"RB-BG"; 
    case '3' : return "RG-R"; 
    case '4'  :return "RG-B"; 
    case '5' : return "RG-G"; 
    case '6' :  return "RG-RB"; 
    case '7' :  return "RG-RG"; 
    case '8' :  return "RG-BG"; 
    case '9' :  return "BG-R";      
    }
    return "Z";

}

//Trying to get 1/4 of these methods to work, colorRed, colrGreen, colorBlue,setWhite
private void colorRed()
{

    Timer timerR = new Timer(750, new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            ballR.setForeground(Color.RED);//or RED, depending
        }
    });
    //timer.setRepeats(false);//don't repeat if you don't want to
    timerR.start();
    ballR.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

}

private void colorGreen()
{

    ballG.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    Timer timerG = new Timer(750, new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            ballG.setForeground(Color.WHITE);//or RED, depending


        }
    });
    timerG.setRepeats(false);
    timerG.start();


}

private void colorBlue()
{
    Timer timerB = new Timer(750, new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            ballB.setForeground(Color.BLUE);//or RED, depending
        }
    });
    //timer.setRepeats(false);
    timerB.start();

    ballR.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
}

private void setWhite()
{
    Timer timer = new Timer(750, new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
             ballB.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
             ballR.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
             ballG.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        }
    });
    //timer.setRepeats(false);
    timer.start();

}





public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                frame frame = new frame();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}


public frame() {
    setTitle("RBG Translator");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 800, 529);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    textEntered = new JTextField();
    textEntered.setText("Enter String...");
    textEntered.setBounds(10, 124, 261, 50);
    contentPane.add(textEntered);
    textEntered.setColumns(10);

    JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
    submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            ballR.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            ballB.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            ballG.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            String input = textEntered.getText().toLowerCase();
            String output = translator(input);
            displayT.setText(output);
            //colorRed();
            colorGreen();

            //colorRed();
            //colorBlue();
            colorGreen();
            colorGreen();



        }
    });
    submit.setBounds(281, 125, 138, 50);
    contentPane.add(submit);

    displayT = new JTextArea();
    displayT.setBounds(10, 246, 409, 234);
    displayT.setLineWrap(true);
    contentPane.add(displayT);

    instructions = new JLabel("Please enter a word or a phrase that you would like to be transalted\r\n");
    instructions.setBounds(10, 11, 396, 14);
    contentPane.add(instructions);

    instructions3 = new JLabel("Below is a translated text of the word or phrase submitted");
    instructions3.setBounds(10, 205, 409, 34);
    contentPane.add(instructions3);

    instructions2 = new JLabel("into RBG code. Currently A-Z, 0-9, and space are permitted.");
    instructions2.setBounds(10, 24, 396, 34);
    contentPane.add(instructions2);

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(470, 25, 304, 169);
    contentPane.add(panel);

    ballR = new JLabel("\u2022");
    panel.add(ballR);
    ballR.setForeground(Color.RED);
    ballR.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 99));

    ballB = new JLabel("\u2022");
    panel.add(ballB);
    ballB.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    ballB.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 99));

    ballG = new JLabel("\u2022");
    panel.add(ballG);
    ballG.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    ballG.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 99));

    textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setColumns(4);
    textArea.setText("a:G   k:G-RB  u:B-R   4:RG-B            "  
            +       "b:G-B  l:R-RG  v:G-G   5:RG-G            "
            +       "c:R-BG m:B-B   w:B-G   6:RG-RB          "
            +       "d:R-RB n:BG    x:G-BG  7:RG-RG          "   
            +       "e:R    o:RB    y:B-BG  8:RG-BG          "
            +       "f:B-RB p:G-R   z:RB-G  9:BG-R            "                      
                +   "g:B-RG q:RB-R  0:RB-RB  :RB-B              "
                +   "h:R-B  r:R-G   1:RB-RG                                        "
                +   "i:RG   s:R-R   2:RB-BG                                        "
            +   "j:G-RG t:B              3:RG-R                    "   );

    textArea.setBounds(429, 246, 345, 234);
    contentPane.add(textArea);

    instructions4 = new JLabel("Key\r\n");
    instructions4.setBounds(429, 205, 345, 34);
    contentPane.add(instructions4);








}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I really don't know what your "codes" are doing, as `R-RB` doesn't seem to make sense, how do you display R, G and B?)

Okay, you need to start by generating some kind of sequence that you want displayed.  This will allow the `Timer` to act as a pseudo loop and update the UI according to the current sequence set

```
private String[] sequence;
private int index;
private Timer timer;
//...
public Test() {
    //...
    JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
    submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            ballR.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            ballB.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            ballG.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            String input = textEntered.getText().toLowerCase();
            String output = translator(input);
            displayT.setText(output);

            timer.stop();

            System.out.println(output);
            List<String> firstPass = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(output.split(" ")));
            List<String> fullPass = new ArrayList<>(25);
            for (String pass : firstPass) {
                if (pass.contains("-")) {
                    String[] parts = pass.split("-");
                    fullPass.addAll(Arrays.asList(parts));
                } else {
                    fullPass.add(pass);
                }
            }

            sequence = fullPass.toArray(new String[fullPass.size()]);
            index = 0;
            timer.start();

        }
    });
```

Basically, this assumes that each space is a separate sequence to be displayed

Next, you need to setup a single `Timer` which can play through the sequences

```
timer = new Timer(750, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ballR.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        ballG.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        ballB.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        if (index < sequence.length) {
            String set = sequence[index];
            System.out.println(index + " = " + set);
            for (char c : set.toCharArray()) {
                if ('R' == c) {
                    ballR.setForeground(Color.RED);
                } else if ('G' == c) {
                    ballG.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
                } else if ('B' == c) {
                    ballB.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                }
            }
        } else {
            timer.stop();
        }
        index++;
    }
});
```

Okay, so, this takes the next `String` sequence and breaks it down into invidual elements, by spiting the `String` on the `-` character (which is why you "codes" don't make sense to me).  It then loops through this set and changes the state of the "balls" accordingly.

The `Timer`continues` until there are no more sequences left...

Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: I call it three times, it only changes it to green and back to white once, with the additional code :/

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Its using JFrame, should i post the whole thing?

Comment: Post only the code which is relevent to the question, which is compilable and runnable and which demonstrates your problem.  We shouldn't have to modify it to get it to run

Comment: I should probably add this bit of information, I am only clicking the action listener once, that could be the problem now that i think about it.... Essentially i want to hit a button to Start the process then have it be automated... SO far this is the only thing i have had progress with. @MadProgrammer

Comment: You want to make it "blink"?

Comment: I want to translate like "red" to R-G/R/R-RB. I have everything set up. But so the put in the word red, they see the output above. After they submit Or click, it i want it to show R-G together, with blue white, Red showing, blue and green white, then Red showing, others white, then RED and BLUE showing, and green white. I have 3 circles that i am using for it. Ill just post my code. @MadProgrammer

Comment: So you want to "play a sequence" of colors?

Comment: Yeah! determined by the input of the user. That's why i am trying to make a method for each color change. Different input will yield different sequences of colors.

Comment: What do the "dashes" mean (`G-B`)?

Comment: It means that it goes together, like  g is green only, then it moves to the next sequence, Green-Blue is Green sequence followed by a blue sequence. so white/white/green, then white/blue/white followed back to back.

Comment: So what does `R-RB` mean?

Comment: sequence of Red only withe blue and green set to white, followed by a sequence of Red and Blue, while the green dot set to white

Comment: The updated code "should" put on a path towards you goal

Comment: @Renuz Hope it helps you towards your goal